# Add Archlinux Mirrorlist in Manjaro

Tags: arch-linux, manjaro, pacman

Manjaro does not install the latest packages from aur or arch repos. But i want to install the latest available packages in arch repos and aur in manjaro.

I then looked into the file `\etc\pacman.d\mirrorlist` the mirrorlist is not same. How can i add the archlinux mirrorlist to manjaro

Answer (score 0):

Doing this would break Manjaro.

There is a Reddit thread linked which in the comments goes over why it is not recommended to do this.
https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/siygbj/manjaro_to_arch_via_mirrors_technical_reasons_why/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).